# Google Glass GDK: updating LiveCards (RemoteViews)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Having Problem updating a LiveCard using remote views.  I am publishing using this code.  I am assuming that you can get the LiveCard using TimelineManager.getLiveCard(id) and then publishing again.  The result I get is two LiveCards.  I am using the same id both times I publish the cards.
As a workaround I am unpublishing and then publishing, but that is not a smooth transition as it shows the 'Okay Glass' between.

```
private void publishCard(Context context) {
    String cardId = "myCard";
    mLiveCard = tm.getLiveCard(cardId);
    mLiveCard.setNonSilent(true);
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.activity_vitals_glass);
    rv = updateViews(rv, pr);
    mLiveCard.setViews(rv);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MenuActivity.class);
    mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0));
    mLiveCard.publish();
}
```

The updateViews() method just sets textviews on the remote view.  What is the proper way to update a LiveCard with RemoteViews?

Comment: What does your activity_vitals_glass.xml look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getLiveCard` creates a new live card, so you should only call it once when your service is started and cache the `LiveCard` instance that you receive.

You can also cache the `RemoteViews` instance at the same time. To update the card after it's published, you'll just need to manually call `setViews` on the `LiveCard` again after you call any of the `RemoteViews` setters.